# Masquerade/change HTTP_USER_AGENT string permanently using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-agent

Is there a way to change/modify the value of user-agent string permanently using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You mean from a web page inside a browser?

No, definitely not. Neither permanently nor temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can't even modify `navigator.userAgent` (at least on my test with Firefox).

So, no.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
alert("User-agent header sent: " + navigator.userAgent);
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){ return "Hello" });
alert("User-agent header sent: " + navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: -1 This is a bad hack, and doesn't actually change anything. You're just overriding the getter, which will have to be done on every single page, and if you're planning on doing that then why are you even bothering to check `userAgent` in the first place?